# CollapsingToolbar, Viewpager having recyclerview and NestedScrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, nestedscrollview

Here is xml of my layout having CollapsingToolbar and viewpager. I am using NestedScrollViews so that the CollapsingToolbarLayout, swipetoreferesh and viewpager work smoothly.

```
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    
        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".wallet_staking_survey.ui.survey_main.SurveyMain2Fragment">
    
    
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBarlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    
                <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_260sdp"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/bg_kyc_progress_level"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
    
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
    
                        <FrameLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
    
                            <com.realresearch.survey.customviews.DonutProgress
                                android:id="@+id/levelProgress"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/_180sdp"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/_180sdp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                app:donut_background_color="@android:color/transparent"
                                app:donut_circle_starting_degree="270"
                                app:donut_finished_color="@color/md_light_green_300"
                                app:donut_finished_stroke_width="5dp"
                                app:donut_text=""
                                app:donut_unfinished_color="@color/md_grey_100"
                                app:donut_unfinished_stroke_width="5dp" />
    
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
    
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tvLevel"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/recipekorea"
                                    android:text="@string/level_2"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/_24sdp" />
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/llKycLevelProgress"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">
    
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tvUpgradKyc"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/recipekorea"
                                    android:text="@string/try_updating_your_kyc_level"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />
    
                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/ivHelp"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_help_24"
                                    android:text="@string/try_updating_your_kyc_level"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </FrameLayout>
    
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/cv_wallet_balance"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_230sdp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_35sdp">
    
    
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center">
    
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/title"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/recipekorea"
                                android:text="@string/my_tnc"
                                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp" />
    
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@id/title">
    
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tvMyTNCBalance"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/recipekorea"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="10,000"
                                    android:textColor="@color/pinkRed"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/_20sdp" />
    
                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/recipekorea"
                                    android:text="@string/tnc"
                                    android:textColor="@color/md_grey_400" />
    
                            </LinearLayout>
    
                        </RelativeLayout>
    
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    
                <!--- ADD TAB_LAYOUT HERE-->
                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/surveyTabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable" />
    
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    
    
            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    
                <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                    android:id="@+id/swipe_to_refresh"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clipToPadding="false"
                        android:fillViewport="true"
                        android:isScrollContainer="false">
                    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                        android:id="@+id/surveyFilterPager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
                </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </layout>
```

I am using single fragment having a recyclerview to show three fragments in viewpager i.e. FragmentA, FragmentB, and FragmentC. Now the problem is FragmentB takes height equals to the content of FragmentA resulting in empty scrollable spaces in FragmentB. Same is the case with FragmentC. Below is the xml of my Fragment having recyclerview.

```
      <layout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_no_survey"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_info" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_semi_bold"
                android:text="@string/no_survey_response"
                android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
                android:textSize="17.3sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/survey_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_semi_bold"
            android:text="@string/all_surveys"
            android:textColor="@color/c_0078AB"
            android:textSize="17.3sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Please help me as i am not able to find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

The second `NestedScrollView` seems to be unnecessary, you can try something like the following codes:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_260sdp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <com.realresearch.survey.customviews.DonutProgress
                        android:id="@+id/levelProgress"
                        app:donut_background_color="@android:color/transparent"
                        app:donut_circle_starting_degree="270"
                        app:donut_finished_color="@color/md_light_green_300"
                        app:donut_finished_stroke_width="5dp"
                        app:donut_text=""
                        app:donut_unfinished_color="@color/md_grey_100"
                        app:donut_unfinished_stroke_width="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_180sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_180sdp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvLevel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="level_2"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_24sdp" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/llKycLevelProgress"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvUpgradKyc"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                                android:text="try_updating_your_kyc_level"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/ivHelp"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_help_24"
                                android:text="try_updating_your_kyc_level"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv_wallet_balance"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_230sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_35sdp">


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:text="my_tnc"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/title">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvMyTNCBalance"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="10,000"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_20sdp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                                android:text="tnc" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <!--- ADD TAB_LAYOUT HERE-->
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/surveyTabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_to_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/surveyFilterPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```